# Possible bug in Java Web Start

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-web-start

I am using Ubuntu operating system with Java version 1.7.0_15 (Iced Tea). I am unable to access the Java web start application. Every time I start it I get message that Java web start requesting JRE 1.7 and then says that it is unable to install so manually install and then it failed to install the JRE. I do not know what to do. 
[image: Error Picture]

Here is my java version[image: Java Version]

Here is few important information
1. I have validated JNLP file using [JaNeLa](http://www.pscode.org/janela/) and there is no error.
2. Ubuntu is opening Application with JRE 1.6 perfectly fine.
3. On Windows every version is running perfectly fine.
4. I have tried with  [deployment tool kit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deployingApplications) but the always redirect me to the Sun page to download the linux version of JRE and even after installing that it again redirect me to the download page.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: I think the question was useful - +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO OpenJDK 7 is not a JRE 7.
You may uninstall it before install oracle jre. Otherwise you have to use sudo update-alternatives to define the default java version

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6

Comment: Thanks for your hints. The issue was due to mozilla plugin was not getting updated properly so creating the issue.

Answer (score 2):

So finally after working whole day I have found the problem with my system. I am not sure why my question got -3 but it was valid question. The problem was with the Java plugin in the Firefox browser. Although I have installed jdk 7 on my machine but the firefox plugin was still pointing to the jre6 so giving error. So I have to manually create the link for the jre 7 in my machine

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/<<location of jre 7>>/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozzilla/plugins
```

Then I restarted the browser and make sure that I have the latest plugin and it started working, So it was not the java installed but it was firefox plugin.

Just FYI, oracle has stopped it support for java plugin for linux due to some licensing so you have to install it manually. Thanks

You can check the installed plug-in by typing 'about:plugins' in your address bar of firefox